# getting an iterable value from intslidergrp

Tags: python, slider, iteration, maya

I have an intSlidergrp to make a given number of spheres, but the method I tried gives me this error: ''int' object is not iterable' so does anyone know how to make a for-loop out of the info given in the slidergrp.

```
def givenLights(*args):   
  wantedLights = cmds.intSliderGrp( sldr2, query=True,value=lights)
  print wantedLights
  for item in wantedLights:
       cmds.polySphere(sx=5, sy=5)

win = cmds.window(title="electrical chords", widthHeight =(300,400),
     topLeftCorner= (200,350))

cmds.columnLayout(adj = True, rs=(10))
lights = 0
sldr2 = cmds.intSliderGrp( field=True, value=lights,minValue=0,maxValue=100)
btn6 = cmds.button(label="Allign given lights",command=givenLights)
cmds.showWindow(win)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself

```
for i in range(inp):
   cmds.polySphere(sx=5, sy=5)
```

I didn't add the range